# Why x<- rnorm(100) does not give equal value to y<-rnorm(a) where a<-100?

Tags: r

```
x <- rnorm(100)
a <- 100
y <- rnorm(a)
# Values of x and y are way different from each other. Why?
```

Why `x <- rnorm(100)` does not give equal value to `y <- rnorm(a)` where `a <- 100` ?

Comment: The problem is that `rnorm` is by definition random. You need to use `set.seed()` to get reproducible results.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/). If `rnorm` produced the same output every time, would you still consider it to be generating random numbers?

Comment: @AndS. even with a `set.seed()`, the results aren't comparable. I guess this is the question here

Comment: You should define the set.seed() for each call. `set.seed(4); x<-rnorm(100)` the first one
`a<-100; set.seed(4);y<-rnorm(a) ` second one. They are same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are not getting comparable results. setting the seed works on my computer:

```r
set.seed(25)
x<-rnorm(100) 

set.seed(25)
a<-100 
y<-rnorm(a) 

all.equal(x, y)
#> [1] TRUE

head(x)
#> [1] -0.2118336 -1.0415911 -1.1533076  0.3215315 -1.5001299 -0.4455333
head(y)
#> [1] -0.2118336 -1.0415911 -1.1533076  0.3215315 -1.5001299 -0.4455333
```

Comment: What is quite interesting is that if you define only one set.seed() for both simulations, then the results would be different.